# Exchagne Web Services - The Autodiscover service couldn't be located

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a Exchange 2013 server (Windows Server 2013). Single server with all roles Domain controller, AD, Exchange server etc. Now I am writing basic Exchange web services sample code.  Below is the code I am trying. If run this code on Exchange server itself, test email gets sent.  But if I run same code on another Windows 10 machine in same domain, it does not works. It gives exception below.

On Windows10 machine I have set DNS IP to point Windows Server 2013(Exchange server), with that I can ping to example.com. What I am missing here, why this code is not working on Windows 10 machine in same domain.

Also did not understand why, it is looking for http://autodiscover.example.com. This is not I have defined anywhere.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("User2001@example.com", "Pass@123");
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("User2001@example.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
        email.ToRecipients.Add("User2002@example.com");
        email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
        email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API");
        email.Send();
    }

    private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
    {
       return true;
    }
```

---

```
    Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetLegacyUserSettings[TSettings](String emailAddress, List`1 redirectionEmailAddresses, Int32& currentHop)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetLegacyUserSettings[TSettings](String emailAddress)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetLegacyUserSettings(String emailAddress, List`1 requestedSettings)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(String userSmtpAddress, UserSettingName[] userSettingNames)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)
   at EWSTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\administrator\source\repos\EWSTest\EWSTest\Program.cs:line 18


    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:16Z">
    Starting SCP lookup for domainName='example.com', root path=''
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:20Z">
    Searching for SCP entries in LDAP://CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:21Z">
    Scanning for SCP pointers Domain=example.com
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:23Z">
    No SCP pointers found for 'Domain=example.com' in configPath='CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com'
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:24Z">
    Scanning for SCP urls for the current computer Site=Default-First-Site-Name
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:24Z">
    Adding (prio 1) 'https://NileshWin12Excg.example.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml' for the 'Site=Default-First-Site-Name' from 'LDAP://CN=NILESHWIN12EXCG,CN=Autodiscover,CN=Protocols,CN=NILESHWIN12EXCG,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=exampleOrg,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com' to the top of the list (exact match)
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:24Z">
    Trying to call Autodiscover for User2001@example.com on https://nileshwin12excg.example.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:25Z">
    POST /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Accept: text/xml
    User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015


    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverRequest" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:25Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
      <Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/requestschema/2006">
        <Request>
          <EMailAddress>User2001@example.com</EMailAddress>
          <AcceptableResponseSchema>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a</AcceptableResponseSchema>
        </Request>
      </Autodiscover>
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
     failed: WebException (The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.)
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    Trying to call Autodiscover for User2001@example.com on https://example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Accept: text/xml
    User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015


    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverRequest" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
      <Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/requestschema/2006">
        <Request>
          <EMailAddress>User2001@example.com</EMailAddress>
          <AcceptableResponseSchema>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a</AcceptableResponseSchema>
        </Request>
      </Autodiscover>
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
     failed: WebException (The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.)
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    Trying to call Autodiscover for User2001@example.com on https://autodiscover.example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Accept: text/xml
    User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015


    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
     failed: WebException (The remote name could not be resolved: 'autodiscover.example.com')
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    Trying to get Autodiscover redirection URL from http://autodiscover.example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    Request error: The remote name could not be resolved: 'autodiscover.example.com'
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    No Autodiscover redirection URL was returned.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:27Z">
    Trying to get Autodiscover host from DNS SRV record for example.com.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:28Z">
    DnsQuery returned error error 'DNS name does not exist' error code 0x0000232B.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:28Z">
    No appropriate SRV record was found.
    </Trace>
    <Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="1" Time="2020-11-08 05:52:28Z">
    No matching Autodiscover DNS SRV records were found.
    </Trace>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you having secure connection issues;

Process

1. Client sends LDAP query to the AD
2. AD returns a list of SCP points
3. Client attempts to connect to the returned points
4. If a valid response comes back, happy days.

In your case the server is returning

https://nileshwin12excg.example.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml - Result : failed: WebException (The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.)

https://example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml - Result : failed: WebException (The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.)

http://autodiscover.example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml - Result : Request error: The remote name could not be resolved: 'autodiscover.example.com'

So it would seem that the client can not establish a trusted connection to https://nileshwin12excg.example.com or https://example.com/, try to get to these URLs from the machine where you are having trouble.  It may be you are using self-signed certs for your web services that are not trusted on the client machine.

**EDIT**

Add

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

To your startup to tell you application to always accept the server certificate as valid.

Comment: On server side I have set ignore client certificate under IIS settings of EWS and AutoDiscoverer. If I tried to access https://example.com or https://nileshwin12excg.example.com , browser opens OWA login page.  Firewall both Windows 10 and Windows Server are disabled.

Comment: From where does this 'autodiscover.example.com' come from? I have not defined it.

Comment: Its a default that the client will try if the all else fails.

Comment: It not the server that is having the issue, the client is trying to validate it's connection.  Give me a tic to see if you can disable SSL from the client side

Comment: I have added to the answer above a code snippet to tell the service point manager to ignore SSL validation, should allow you code to work.

Comment: Where I can find this certificate on server? So instead of ignoring it, I can install it on client machine.

Comment: You will need to identify the certificate that you are using on the server IIS for HTTPS, Once you have identified the certificate, you will need to look at the certificate details and find the CA that was used to create the certificate.  One you have done this open certificate manager then go to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" / "Certificate" find the CA certificate and export it.   You can the import this certificate into "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" / "Certificate" on the client machine and it will trust the servers signing on HTTPS connections.

Comment: You should already have this somewhere from when you setup the HTTPS on IIS.